# Accessing CSS height value (universal method)?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to know if it is possible to make the `heightVal` variable of this code snippet act universally.  Meaning I need it to access the height of whatever element I pass in as the `box` parameter and store it so that it can be used to reset the element to its original height.  Using the offsetHeight property has not worked for me because the value is automatically reset when the function is accessed for the second time. (I am trying to make this function universally applicable to any element).

```
function expand(box){
  var heightVal = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].style.height;

  if(box.style.height != "20px"){
    box.style.height = "20px";
  }
  else{
    box.style.height = heightVal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you store it as an attribute on the DOM node?

Instead of doing `var heightVal =`, do `box.my_height =`. Or you can even use the HTML5 `data-XXX` attributes if you really don't like it being in JS only.

```
function expand(box){
  if(box.style.height != "20px"){
    box.my_old_height = box.style.height;
    box.style.height = "20px";
  }
  else{
    box.style.height = box.my_old_height;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Proud_to_be_Noob `box` is a Javascript object representing a DOM node. Like any Javascript object, you may set arbitrary attributes on it, including ones you make up yourself.

Comment: yeah, i just did that and it works, however how do i make it work when i use a different <div> element that has a different height, without copying the code and altering the `document.stylesheet` connection for each individual div I use it on?  That is the main problem, I want the code to be able to universally minimize and the restore any <div> or other element that I pass in to the function.

Comment: @Proud_to_be_Noob I... Do not understand how you're using `document.stylesheet` if you can both save and restore the element's previous height from its DOM node alone.

Comment: okay well thats exactly what I'm asking, how can I avoid using document.stylesheet (i don't want to have to use that).  I have already tried `box.my_height = box.offsetHeight` doesnt work, and I've tried many other things as well such as `var myHeight = box.style.height` but that one only works if I declare the height as an inline style which I want to keep in the external stylesheet.

Comment: @Proud_to_be_Noob I've pasted in some code for what I was suggesting. I still don't understand how or why `document.stylesheet` would be in there...